# Align two SVG cliping path's

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible to implement [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7q4wu.png) using SVG clipping-paths? Using only HTML and CSS isn't possible...

I manage to get almost all done, but I can't align the two clip paths.

https://jsfiddle.net/jgfqd51b/1/

```
<div class="back">
  <div class="left">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  </div>
</div>

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipLeft" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="m 0.82265928,0 c 0,0 0,0.1 0.10283241,0.3 C 1.147517,0.74343146 0.80259703,1 0.80259703,1 L 0,1 0,0 z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipRight" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="m 1,2e-8 -0.96585786,0 C 0.0612794,0.23647848 0.1584381,0.28563057 0.1552199,0.59160234 0.1569876,0.85447923 0,0.99999997 0,0.99999997 l 1,0 z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Any ideas or a different approach?

Comment: Use an SVG editor such as Inkscape to draw whatever shapes you want.

Comment: I used Inkscape to draw the two sides of the image to create the clipping hover the gradient background.